# android: AbsListView.OnScrollListener SCROLL_STATE_IDLE is not called after SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL (Version 2.1)

Tags: android, listview, android-sdk-2.1

I have a problem with android version 2.1. It looks like a bug.

I attached an `OnScrollListener` to my listView.

I'm using the method `onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)` for monitoring the scroll's state of my listview.

The scrollstate could assume 3 value (taken from the documentation):

1. **SCROLL_STATE_FLING**: The user had
   previously been scrolling using
   touch and had performed a fling. The
   animation is now coasting to a stop
2. **SCROLL_STATE_IDLE**:The view is not
   scrolling. Note navigating the list
   using the trackball counts as being
   in the idle state since these
   transitions are not animated.
3. **SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL**:The user
   is scrolling using touch, and their
   finger is still on the screen

I assume that the **SCROLL_STATE_IDLE** will always be passed after one of other two states.
It's always true excepted for android version 2.1.
**SCROLL_STATE_IDLE** is not passed after **SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL**
The problem happens also if you stop the fling by a touch instead of let the scroll stop by itself.
This strange behaviour leaves my listView in an unconsistate state.

Someonelse has the same problem? 
Suggestion for a "not-so-dirty" work around?

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a bug that has been registered for this case.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5086

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue on 2.2.

If the list is big enough, and I scroll down up, I got first CROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL while my finger is on the screen. When my finger leave the screen I got the SCROLL_STATE_FLING. When my view has stopped moving I got the SCROLL_STATE_IDLE.

But, if during scroll, it reaches either View Top or Bottom, I only scroll/fling values and never the idle.

I checked out Shelves project from Romain Guy and his implementation suffer the same issue on 2.2.x I'm wondering if he had noticed yet.

I haven't tried yet with 2.3.x

Answer (score 2):

I found something of a workaround for this (at least for API level 9+, where I'm still seeing the bug). I'm using a GridView, but I believe this should also work for ListView.

I'm using a subclass of GridView where I am detecting the overscroll (top or bottom):

```
 public class CustomGridView {
   private boolean mIsOverScrolled = false;

   @Override
   protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, 
                       boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
     mIsOverScrolled = true;
     super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
   }

   public boolean isOverScrolled() {
     return mOsOverScrolled;
   }

   public void clearOverScroll() {
     mIsOverScrolled = false;
   }
 }
```

Then, in my OnScrollListener of CustomGridView, I have:

```
 @Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {
   if (gridView.isOverScrolled()) {
     gridView.clearOverScroll();
   }

   // ...
 }
```

Now when I'm checking for `OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, I also check if `!gridView.isOverScrolled()`. I'm not sure if that fixes your specific use cases, but hopefully you can use the additional piece of info to determine your current state despite the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem and posted a workaround on the bug list mentioned by DeRagan:
[Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5086#c7)